# Best and secure way to send parameters in URL

Tags: php, security, url, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am working on a website in which there would be functionalities to update and delete data on the basis of id. Now the thing I am worried about is like my url would be

> www.example.com/public/controller/action/1

if the action would be `delete`, any person can `change id from 1 to 2` in url and the data with id 2 would get deleted. What would be the best way to keep the flow secure. I am using Zf2 and Doctrine2... Any suggestions please !!! And moreover I am keeping ids hidden in fields, anybody can use firebug to change the value in fields, is there any way to protect data from that too?

Would any encryption-decryption way would make it secure, like if anybody even edits the encrypted value, after decrypting it would not result in a required id? Which one would be good?

Comment: Do these users require access/privileges to delete said data?

Comment: @dbh well thats the problem no privilege.. e.g., like group chatting, there are multiple comments from different people, if someone clicks on delete on one comment and changes id in that, someone's else would get deleted

Comment: unless you're going to implement some kind of permission check, there's not way to prevent someone from changing the IDs and going to a different URL

Comment: @AndrewBrown any encryption-decryption way ??

Comment: what would you try encrypting? the only thing I can possibly think of is a 'security by obscurity' method where you send an encrypted ID, and then when you decrypt it see if the resulting ID actually exists. but I would strongly recommend not going down that path.

Comment: If you want ID's to be manupulation safe, you have to get hashed ID's (and I'm not talking about `md5(1)` :D Other than that you can't really stop users from manipulating the URL, if users can delete/edit all posts and not just their own.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am looking forward to make it more better

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should worry less about what happens when people change parameters within the URL or try to hack something into your HTML (hidden fields), as much more you should worry about what your users are actually allowed to do.

If an admin is allowed to delete all **posts** for example, then it doesn't matter if he changes `domain.com/post/delete/1` into `domain.com/post/delete/42`. If admins are supposed to delete everything they can. So let them just change it as much as they want to.

If admins however are only allowed to gain administrative privileges to their own entries, then you need to work this into your Service-Layer. The Service-Layer would check for permissions of the current user against the currently requested object. My personal favorite would be [`ZfcRbac`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac).

If however you want to make it more difficult for people to actually change IDs, then you should give every entry a unique hash. So for example the url would be `domain.com/post/delete/12acd-4a7f7c6-4a7f7c6-12acd-4a7f7c6` or something like that.

**TL/DR** don't worry what happens when people change stuff within the URL/HTML, simply worry about Authentication and Permissions in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can change id to some_random_string (based on timestamp to make it unique) and search databese for that.
There is no chance that user would guess that random string.
And second check in controller that logged user have rights to CRUD actions.

You can use https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser (with second module for Doctrine)
to make auth and in controller you can check if user is logged

```
if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity()) {
    $user = $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity();
    if($user->systemRole=='admin')//you can make switch for that
    {
      //can edit/delete/create
    }
}
```

To make this work you must copy UserEntity from that module and add systemRole. (check documentation for zfc-user for that)

Comment: I usually use this aproach it seems to be fast and clean. If you see yourself using this to moch adding a method to zfc which does such a comparission might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

1- try to check authorization in action . 
2- In some case you can save some data such as entity id in session on page load and then only call delete.
3- any encryption algorithm has one (or more) key . some important part of security management is key management . if you have implementation of an algorithm in PHP and Javascript then you should have key in both side for decryption (user can find your keys in client side code)
4- hash may help you . hash do,'t need to key and make your data unreadable but hacker can call your url with hash data
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

**Update 1 :** 
for encryption you can use accessible data on server and client as key . for example use "url character count" as key 
url character count : 10 
id (plain data) : 23 
id (encrypted and use for send to server ) 33 = 23 + 10 
on server you should decrypt id (id = id - url character count)

important point :
encryption algorithm should be extremely minified and obfuscate on client .

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way to send a url with data is over a secure connection with ssl (https).  However, I don't think this is the question you are meaning to ask.

I think you are wanting to prevent certain people or groups of people (roles) from accessing certain resources.  If this is the case, you need an access control list, and you should use the \Zend\Permissions\Acl component.

Edit:

The best way to encrypt data in PHP is to use a modern reversible-encryption functions like `mcrypt_encrypt` and `mcrypt_decrypt`.

However, this is simply obscuring the url, it does not fully protect you from someone simply making a robot to check all the delete urls available (given, there may be quite a few).

The only bulletproof way of protecting certain pages (resources) is to use some type of access control.  Say for instance, you only want a particular user to be able to delete their own posts.  You could have an action `deleteMyPost`.  (I am presuming you have a user login to the site in order to perform actions, otherwise, all bets are off).  When someone goes to www.mysite.com/public/controller/deleteMyPost/1, the action or the ACL will check if the id of 1 is a post of the logged in user.  If not, the user will be redirected away from the page in some fashion, maybe with a `header('Location: <url>')` call.

Comment: Well I did not mean exactly that, I am asking about best way to send params in urls... May be best way of encrypting my ids visible in url which might not be editable and if they are edited, after getting converted they do not get converted into some number.. I dont know if anything like that is possible

Comment: Using HTTPS does not prevent tampering of the URL.

Comment: @Gumbo Yes.  Nothing prevents tampering with the URL.  I guess I should have added a note to say where my edit occurred.  I have done so now.  Once I learned that Deepanshu wanted to know about encrypting/decrypting url components, I stated functions he could use to do so.  I still think my answer applies, is in line with all other answers (all of which I agree with), and gives a response to what Deepanshu was originally asking, specifically what functions are available for encrypting and decrypting url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking about relates to ACL which ZendFramework has a [perfectly working library](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.acl.html) for it. In ACL, you will first configure who can do what on which resource, and then later you will query it to see if some request by some user is permitted or not. Here are the parts of an ACL:

- User
- Action
- Resource

For instance:

- User: Mehran
- Action: Delete
- Resource: Any record of table T1

But in ZF Action and Resource are merge into one which is no big deal. In ZF you need to say `Action_Resource` instead. The thing I'm going to expand here is the types of resources you might face. In my opinion there are two:

1. Static resources.
2. Dynamic Resources.

Static resources are those that you can list (completely) while you are designing your software. e.g. you might have **posts** in your software, which you might want to grant the permission to some user to delete them. If you won't give some other user such permission, then he/she can not delete any of the posts. But if you do give it to someone, then he can delete any post he wants (assuming we are not including dynamic resources yet). In other words, static resources are **types of dynamic resources**.

Moreover, we have dynamic resources which do not exists until the software is deployed. In fact dynamic resources are created by end user. So they've got owners. You might want to grant the delete permission of dynamic resources to their owners only. Expanding the same example as before, any specific **post** could be a dynamic resource.

Before I come to conclusion, I would like to expand the types of actions in computer world (in general). Usually you can assume there are only four types of action:

1. Create
2. Modify
3. Delete
4. Read

If you want to check the permission for one of the actions above, only **Create** deals with static resources and the rest are talking about dynamic ones. That is, when you are creating a **post** there's no dynamic resource created yet so all you can do is to stick to static one instead. But in all the rest of action types, there's always a dynamic resource to include in your permission check.

Now putting the two types of resources side by side, you've got a decision to make. If a dynamic resource is available, should I check the permission with dynamic resource or its static (since all dynamic resources will always have a static one as their type)? The answer to this question is usually: **both of them**. Here's how:

1. User can delete if: he has access to static **and** dynamic resource.
2. User can delete if: he has access to static **or** dynamic resource.

In first scenario any user can delete his own resources if he's granted the permission. But no one else can ever do so. In the second case, any owner can delete his own resource regardless of any other permission granted or not. But you can also grant the deletion permission to some administrator who is not the owner. Usually the later case is preferred.

Having said all this, in your case you are talking about checking the access to some dynamic resource and you need to implement an ACL for it.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a dynamic method:

The essence of this method is based on identifying a single use.

1 - You create a new unique identifier for each identifiers.
for example, for the identifier $id1 you can do:

```
$new_id1 = uniqid(sha1("$id1")). / / Just for example
```

And you put all these identifiers in an array:

```
array ($new_id1 => $ id1,
       $new_id2 => $ id2,
       .....
       / / I advise you to have a trace logger for in case of problems.
```

2 - You put this array in session (or cache) after delete if it already existed

3 - You create links with new identifier:

```
<A href = "/Controller/Action/". $new_id1 . "> link text </ a>
```

The user only has access to his page identifiers (and thus for which it has the rights) and will be hard (very very ... very hard :) ) pressed to find another identifier.

4 - When PHP retrieve the identifier $new_id1, it will fetch the array in session (or cache) to get the real identifier ($id1).

5 - Delete the array from the session (or cache) to do not be able to use (single use)

This method can be enhanced depending on your level of requirement.

- You can use a form instead of a link.

  < a onclick="submit_form(" . $new_id1 . ")">Your text link < / a>
  ...

The submit_form() fill the hidden element with the good value
You can add a Hash element for the protection from CSRF attacks.

- If the identifier php side is not in the array, you can disconnect the person and possibly put on a black list
- There are other possibility as dynamic routing. generating a url without controller and with the new id, and if this id is recognized, route it to the correct controller.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
$token = sha1("id=1&action=delete");

$url = "www.mysite.com/public/controller/action/delete/id/1/token/".$token;
```

on target page create token for passed parameters and cross check with url token. If it's matched then consider it as valid input (You may add timstamp to generate token for better security)

Answer (score 0):

I would simply advise using POST instead of GET.

> ## When to use GET?
>
> Information sent from a form with the GET method is visible to
>   everyone (all variable names and values are displayed in the URL). GET
>   also has limits on the amount of information to send. The limitation
>   is about 2000 characters. However, because the variables are displayed
>   in the URL, it is possible to bookmark the page. This can be useful in
>   some cases.
>
> GET may be used for sending non-sensitive data.
>
> Note: GET should NEVER be used for sending passwords or other
>   sensitive information!
>
> ## When to use POST?
>
> Information sent from a form with the POST method is invisible to
>   others (all names/values are embedded within the body of the HTTP
>   request) and has no limits on the amount of information to send.
>
> Moreover POST supports advanced functionality such as support for
>   multi-part binary input while uploading files to server.
>
> However, because the variables are not displayed in the URL, it is not
>   possible to bookmark the page.