# Secure a PHP API with CSRF protection

Tags: php, api

I have an api endpoint which reads the json data and store to backend every second.

Now i need to secure this endpoint before i pass it to the client, such a way that 
the client needs to use the generated token and only if the token is valid then the API should execute.

Below i have written a code to generate random token.

```
<?php

    /*To generate a cryptographically secure token */

    //Generate a random string.
    $token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

    //Convert the binary data into hexadecimal representation.
    $token = bin2hex($token);

    echo 'TOKEN: '.$token;

?>
```

How to i integrate this with my api and ask my client to append the generated tokens as headers in the actual api endpoint url.

My API url is like:   http://demo.abc.com/sample.php

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if (!empty($data)):
header('Content-Type:text/plain');

function db_connect()
{
   ... 
}

function db_query($query)
{
    ...
}

$arraykey = array_keys($data);
$array    = $data[$arraykey[0]];

try {
    ....
    echo 'Data Successfully inserted!!<br />';
    ....
}


catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
endif;
?>
```

Client need to use the headers something like :

http://demo.abc.com/sample.php?token='< whateveris_generated>'

Or require any other secure or better way of passing the token to API

Comment: You could try using `urlencode` or `sha1` if you are worried about the token being snatched

Comment: Could you please explain with eg or link on how i use sha1 with my existing endpoint

Comment: something like `$finalToken= sha1($token);` Also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470754/best-and-secure-way-to-send-parameters-in-url

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is CSRF protection, your API is not vulnerable to it as long as the token is not sent automatically with the request (for example, it's not stored as a cookie). If you are sending the token over HTTP, then it can be sniffed from the traffic though, so you may want to use HTTPS instead. I'd also recommend sending the auth token in an HTTP header, not in the query string.

Comment: Im particularly not worried about using only CSRF, (need an alternate way to make it secure) yes im passing the api over http and could you pls show how to send token over http header

Comment: With HTTP it an be sniffed relatively easily no matter where you send it. You should use HTTPS. Sending the token in a header depends on what you use to send it. In the API you can get it from the `$_SERVER` superglobal. Say you send it in the Authorization header, you can access it via `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']`

Comment: we have a server existing with http(not authorized to change the domain now!!), any suggestion on how to make this api secure

Comment: You don't have to change the domain, just switch the protocol to HTTPS. You can use letsencrypt for example.